# Why isn't typescript throwing an error when I do not pass down props to a functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Why isn't typescript throwing an error when I do not pass down props to a functional component?

This code will work:

```
interface Props{
id: string;
className?: string;


}

export const Buttons: React.FC<Props> = () => {

  return(

    <section>

      <div className="container">

        <p>Hellow World</p>

      </div>

    </section>

  );
}
```

The same than this one:

```
interface Props{
id: string;
className?: string;


}

export const Buttons: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {

  return(

    <section id={props.id}>

      <div className="container">

        <p>Hellow World</p>

      </div>

    </section>

  );
}
```

props is passed in the second one but not in the first. Why is typescript no able to detect that I'm not passing down the props to my functional component?

Comment: What about to add the interface in your function parameter? I believe that's the missing part in your code.

```
export const Buttons: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript doesn't require you to declare all function variables. That's a feature it inherits from JavaScript itself. You can define a function implementation that omits variables - and still access them through the `arguments` variable.

Answer (score 0):

`const Buttons: React.FC<Props>` means "now comes a function that requires some specific arguments". 
But nothing requires you to actually *use* those arguments.

One side of the `=` is the outside interface. The other side is what you internally do with it.
Maybe you know that tomorrow you will need those props, but you don't need them today? Go ahead, already define that type, requiring you to pass in those parameters. You can use them later when the need arises.